# React proxy doesn't work on npm run build

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to commnunicate with back-end server by using axios.
So I added proxy in package.json like below.

package.json

```
  "proxy": "http://backend:8080",
```

It works well with 'npm start', but when I try 'npm run build', I am unable to communicate with the backend.

```
 axios.get('/member/login',{
        headers :{
          Authorization : hash
        }
      })
```

So I tried to put full url like below but still not communicating.

```
 axios.get('http://backend:8080/member/login',{
        headers :{
          Authorization : hash
        }
      })
```

How can I solve this problem??

It seems to be deployed through server.js after npm run build.So just in case, I'll upload the server.js code as well.

server.js

```
const http=require("http");
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

const port = 3000;

app.get("/ping",(req,res) =>{
    res.send("pong");
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"build")));
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname+'/server/build'))

app.get("/*",(req,res) => {
    res.set({
        "Cache-Control":"no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
        Pragma:"no-cache",
        Date:Date.now()
    });
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"build","index.html"));
});

http.createServer(app).listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`app listening arr ${port})`);
});
```

Comment: @monim Tried it but still not working

Comment: the proxy in package.json works only for dev environment

Comment: yeah you have to remove the proxy if you're building and/or deploying

Comment: Do I have to remove proxy in package.json when deploy?? @yagyesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**proxy** feature is only for development (with `npm start`) . witch means It is not meant for production (with `npm build`).  you can check it [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)

In [production](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/) (`npm run build`) it  just creates the static files to deploy which makes proxying doesn't make sense because there is no development server in this phase. instead, now you'll have to serve your static files on any server you choose. For example, in **nginx server** you can use
[proxy_pass](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

Comment: Thank's it helped me alot. I used @CrossOrigin annotation to solve it!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install and import axios?

`npm install axios`

`import axios from 'axios';`

Comment: Not a package installation problem, based on description

Answer (score 0):

React uses http://localhost:3000/ by default , backend port could be anything other than 3000.
say if the backend port is 8080, then url to get data : http://localhost:8080/

Answer (score 0):

You could try [using defaults](https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults):

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://backend:8080';
```